# Account Console internal server error on all buttons

Tags: keycloak

Using the keycloak docker image (`11.0.1`), as a user I can login to

```
http://localhost:9990/auth/realms/myrealm/account/
```

But when I click on any button (e.g. `cancel` on the edit account page), it shows:

```
We are sorry...
An internal server error has occurred
```

I looked in to the dev tools and see that the `POST http://localhost:9990/auth/realms/myrealm/account/` results in a `403 Forbidden`.

I checked the effective roles of that specific user. In Role Mappings > Client Roles > Account > it shows `manage-account` and `view-profile` as effective permissions.

Also, the keycloak server logs show nothing that would help me to understand what the problem is (having set `ROOT_LOGLEVEL: ALL` and `KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: ALL`)

```
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,143 DEBUG [io.undertow.request] (default I/O-11) Matched prefix path /auth for path /auth/realms/myrealm/account/
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,145 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-1) Attempting to authenticate /auth/realms/myrealm/account/, authentication required: false
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,145 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-1) Authentication outcome was NOT_ATTEMPTED with method io.undertow.security.impl.CachedAuthenticatedSessionMechanism@66fae46c for /auth/realms/myrealm/account/
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,145 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.security] (default task-1) Authentication result was ATTEMPTED for /auth/realms/myrealm/account/
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,145 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (default task-1) new JtaTransactionWrapper
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,145 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (default task-1) was existing? false
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,147 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-1) RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /realms/myrealm/account/
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,147 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession] (default task-1) realm by name cache hit: myrealm
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,147 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession] (default task-1) by id cache hit: myrealm
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,148 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession] (default task-1) client by name cache hit: account
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,148 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession] (default task-1) client by id cache hit: account
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,148 TRACE [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory] (default task-1) Create JpaConnectionProvider
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,148 DEBUG [org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl] (default task-1) Hibernate RegisteredSynchronization successfully registered with JTA platform
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,149 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services.util.CookieHelper] (default task-1) Couldnt find cookie {0}, trying {1}
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,150 TRACE [org.keycloak.keys.DefaultKeyManager] (default task-1) Found key: realm=myrealm kid=cd7dde2b-a543-42cf-ba5c-f60ae03d3c78 algorithm=HS256 use=SIG
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,150 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession] (default task-1) by id cache hit: myrealm
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,150 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession] (default task-1) getuserById a353603c-66cf-4488-bd1b-fea8ae51a9db
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,150 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession] (default task-1) getuserById a353603c-66cf-4488-bd1b-fea8ae51a9db
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,150 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession] (default task-1) return managedusers
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,151 TRACE [org.keycloak.keys.DefaultKeyManager] (default task-1) Active key found: realm=myrealm kid=cd7dde2b-a543-42cf-ba5c-f60ae03d3c78 algorithm=HS256 use=SIG
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,151 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services.managers.AuthenticationManager] (default task-1) Create login cookie - name: KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY, path: /auth/realms/myrealm/, max-age: -1
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,154 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession] (default task-1) realm by name cache hit: myrealm
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,154 TRACE [org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession] (default task-1) by id cache hit: myrealm
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,155 DEBUG [freemarker.cache] (default task-1) Couldn't find template in cache for "error.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,155 DEBUG [freemarker.cache] (default task-1) TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("error_en_US.ftl"): Not found
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,155 DEBUG [freemarker.cache] (default task-1) TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("error_en.ftl"): Not found
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,155 DEBUG [freemarker.cache] (default task-1) TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("error.ftl"): Found
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,156 DEBUG [freemarker.cache] (default task-1) Loading template for "error.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed) from "file:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/base/login/error.ftl"
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,157 DEBUG [freemarker.cache] (default task-1) Couldn't find template in cache for "template.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,157 DEBUG [freemarker.cache] (default task-1) TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("template_en_US.ftl"): Not found
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,157 DEBUG [freemarker.cache] (default task-1) TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("template_en.ftl"): Not found
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,158 DEBUG [freemarker.cache] (default task-1) TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("template.ftl"): Found
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,158 DEBUG [freemarker.cache] (default task-1) Loading template for "template.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed) from "file:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/base/login/template.ftl"
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,176 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-1) MessageBodyWriter: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory$SortedKey
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,176 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-1) MessageBodyWriter: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StringTextStar
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,176 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-1) MessageBodyWriter: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StringTextStar
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,176 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-1) Interceptor Context: org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerWriterInterceptorContext,  Method : proceed
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,176 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-1) WriterInterceptor: org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalSigningInterceptor
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,176 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.i18n] (default task-1) Interceptor : org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalSigningInterceptor,  Method : aroundWriteTo
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,176 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-1) Interceptor Context: org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerWriterInterceptorContext,  Method : proceed
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,176 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-1) MessageBodyWriter: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory$SortedKey
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,176 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-1) MessageBodyWriter: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StringTextStar
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,177 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (default task-1) JtaTransactionWrapper rollback
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,177 DEBUG [org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl] (default task-1) Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,177 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl] (default task-1) On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,177 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (default task-1) JtaTransactionWrapper end
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,177 TRACE [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProvider] (default task-1) DefaultJpaConnectionProvider close()
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,457 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) new JtaTransactionWrapper
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,457 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) was existing? false
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,457 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) JtaTransactionWrapper  commit
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,458 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) JtaTransactionWrapper end
keycloak_1  | 23:11:55,458 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ScheduledTaskRunner] (Timer-2) Executed scheduled task AbstractLastSessionRefreshStoreFactory$$Lambda$2004/0x0000000841634040
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a bug in 11.0.1 see https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-15260?jql=project%20%3D%20keycloak%20and%20fixVersion%20%3D%2011.0.2

Updating the image to `11.0.2` solves the issue.